# Iterate rows and compare one row column value to next row column value in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window, row

I need help creating the following logic.
I have a df with daily information for different customers, like in this example:

```
val df = Seq(
(1, "2021-08-15", 10),
(1, "2021-08-16", 10),
(1, "2021-08-17", 12),
(2, "2021-08-15", 5),
(2, "2021-08-16", 5)
.toDF("id", "date", "money")
```

I want to create an additional column using a condition, in which the column is true if the value for the same customer on the previous date is equal to today's value and false if the values change. The condition is for each specific customer and it shouldn't consider other customers.

My ideal final output would be:

```
// +---+----------+-----+--------------+
// | id|date      |money|col-comparison|
// +---+----------+-----+--------------+
// |  1|2021-08-15| 10  |          null|
// |  1|2021-08-16| 10  |          true|
// |  1|2021-08-17| 12  |         false|
// |  2|2021-08-15|  5  |          null|
// |  2|2021-08-16|  5  |          true|
```

I created this code, but its not giving me the desired output:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

def compareCol1(curr: Column, prev: Column): Column = curr === prev

val window = Window.orderBy("id", "date")

df.withColumn("col-comparison", compareCol1($"money", lag("money", 1).over(window)))
```

The issue that I'm having with the code is that it doesn't understand that comparisons should only be between the same ID. The input that I'm getting is this one:

```
// +---+----------+-----+--------------+
// | id|date      |money|col-comparison|
// +---+----------+-----+--------------+
// |  1|2021-08-15| 10  |          null|
// |  1|2021-08-16| 10  |          true|
// |  1|2021-08-17| 12  |         false|
// |  2|2021-08-15|  5  |         false|
// |  2|2021-08-16|  5  |          true|
```

Instead of having one comparison per id, its always comparing it to the previous value in the dataset.

Does someone know how I can fix this? Maybe its a very easy question but I'm not sure how to do it!

Comment: try `Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")`